# Android overlapping profile photos view

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I am trying to implement this view.

[image]

I tried it this way.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/images"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_default"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/white_two"
                app:civ_shadow="false"/>

            <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_default"
                android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                app:civ_shadow="false"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

But the second picture stays above the first and I want it the other way around. I would add the images programmatically so I don't think I could use RelativeLayout. Is this possible or is there an existing Android library for this already?

Comment: Have you tried with FrameLayout?

Comment: put your code to add ImageView .

Comment: user RelativeLayout and marginStart or end -2dp

Comment: hopefully this helps you https://github.com/KartikPrajapati/StackImageView

Comment: @ZahoorSaleem this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `android:elevation="8dp"` in your first code to made your first over the second view

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to generate the images programmatically.

[image]

```
 val circleImageView1 = CircleImageView(context)
        circleImageView1.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Tools.dpToPx(40), Tools.dpToPx(40))
        circleImageView1.borderWidth = 1
        circleImageView1.borderColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white_two)
        circleImageView1.circleBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue)
        circleImageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_default)

        val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Tools.dpToPx(40), Tools.dpToPx(40))
        layoutParams.setMargins(Tools.dpToPx(-10), 0, 0, 0)

        val circleImageView2 = CircleImageView(context)
        circleImageView2.layoutParams = layoutParams
        circleImageView2.borderWidth = 1
        circleImageView2.borderColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white_two)
        circleImageView2.circleBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)
        circleImageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_default)

        val circleImageView3 = CircleImageView(context)
        circleImageView3.layoutParams = layoutParams
        circleImageView3.borderWidth = 1
        circleImageView3.borderColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white_two)
        circleImageView3.circleBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green)
        circleImageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_default)

        itemView.images.addView(circleImageView1)
        itemView.images.addView(circleImageView2)
        itemView.images.addView(circleImageView3)

        itemView.images.scaleX = -1.0f
```

This works for now I just need to make sure to go through the list of images reversely since order is important.